# App crash but no app specific code in stack trace

Tags: android

Users of recent Android phones are reporting crashes of my app after upgrading to Android 9.

The stacktrace is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException:
at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService.onUpdateNavBarColor (InputMethodService.java:3294)
at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService.access$1000 (InputMethodService.java:301)
at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService$InputMethodSessionImpl.updateNavBarColor (InputMethodService.java:1013)
at android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodSessionWrapper.executeMessage (IInputMethodSessionWrapper.java:140)
at com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller.executeOrSendMessage (HandlerCaller.java:61)
at android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodSessionWrapper.updateNavBarColor (IInputMethodSessionWrapper.java:233)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.updateNaviBarColor (InputMethodManager.java:1289)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.showSoftInput (InputMethodManager.java:1277)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.showSoftInput (InputMethodManager.java:1187)
at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$SearchAutoComplete.setImeVisibility (SearchView.java:2009)
at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$SearchAutoComplete.access$000 (SearchView.java:1822)
at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.onSearchClicked (SearchView.java:1226)
at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$5.onClick (SearchView.java:978)
at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:7333)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal (View.java:7299)
at android.view.View.access$3200 (View.java:846)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:27774)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6981)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

(see also https://gist.github.com/githubomane/c083cf047c2d197bf29fdb505960eeb9)

Unfortunately, these are all android OS/library methods and I don't know where in this I could change anything? Is there a way to get additional insights on this? Searching for `onUpdateNavBarColor` or `updateNaviBarColor` do not bring up any results on Google.

My app implements a custom IME and it also uses the SearchView, but how can I decide where the potential error is?

Comment: do you have any searchview in your app? Error seems to be related to that

Comment: The `DeadObjectException` in your logs could also be relevant - could you post the code where you suspect the crash is happening?

Comment: @VivekMishra I have a searchView in https://github.com/PhilippC/keepass2android/blob/master/src/keepass2android/GroupBaseActivity.cs and I just found that there is deprecated code in line 874, but do you think this could be related?

Comment: @PPartisan the app source code is on https://github.com/PhilippC/keepass2android/blob/master/src/, but it's hard to tell what the DeadObjectException could come from. Users say they receive this problem when opening a searchview in my app when they have my InputMethod enabled - I doubt that the app is killed in this scenario, right?

Comment: It seems you are using xamarin for development. But if it is deprecated, you can give the alternative a try.

Comment: @Philipp from your last comment, to me it seems like searchview is not able to capture input from your inputMethod resulting in null pointer exception.